# Can not get paginate parameters using func_get_arg() function in Model

Tags: cakephp, cakephp3

I'm updating cakephp2 to cakephp3.
For model side, I can not get paginate parameters using func_get_arg() function in Model.
How can I get it?

I want to keep using func_get_arg() because other Model classes have also same logic.

```
class TopController extends AppController {

  public function showTop() {
    $query = array(
      'limit' => 5,
      'extra' => array(
        'data' => 'test', 
      ),
    );

    $topRawTable = TableRegistry::get('TopRawSql');
    $pages = $this->Paginator->paginate($topRawTable->paginate($query)); //Error occur
  }
}

class TopRawSqlTable extends Table {

  public $useTable = false;
  
  function paginate()
  {
    $extra = func_get_arg(6); // null
    $limit = func_get_arg(3); // null
    $page = func_get_arg(4); // null

    // Execute custom query
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I knew that CakePHP2 supports override paginate() and paginateCount() functions. But CakePHP3 DOESN'T support override paginate() and paginateCount(). That's why I couldn't get parameters by func_get_arg().

So, I switched to use CakePHP2 paginator feature.